# is there a way a can get my react app to work? it throws an error when i try the "npm start command"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I successfully installed create-react-app but when I run the following command:

```
npm start
```

it throws this error:

> `npm err missing script: start`

How can get my react app to work?

Comment: try npm run start